# Spring SAML - AuthResponse doesn't come to SP if it honors only https

Tags: spring, https, single-sign-on, saml, spring-saml

I am using spring-saml extension and tried to create a POC in tomcat when tomcat only accepts the https (yes no http) and on the web entry, end user it taken to the IDP's screen and after authentication, never comes back to the SP pages because SP never gets the AuthResponse from iDP.

Here is the spring-saml security configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- Enable auto-wiring -->
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <!-- Scan for auto-wiring classes in spring saml packages -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.springframework.security.saml"/>

    <!-- Unsecured pages -->
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/favicon.ico"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/logout.jsp"/>

    <!-- Security for the administration UI -->
    <security:http pattern="/saml/web/**" access-denied-page="/saml/web/metadata/login">
    <security:form-login login-processing-url="/saml/web/login" login-page="/saml/web/metadata/login" default-target-url="/saml/web/metadata"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/metadata/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/saml/web/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
    <!-- <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/> -->
    </security:http>

    <!-- Secured pages with SAML as entry point -->
    <security:http entry-point-ref="samlEntryPoint">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY"/>
    <security:custom-filter before="FIRST" ref="metadataGeneratorFilter"/>
    <security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
    </security:http>

    <!-- Filters for processing of SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <security:filter-chain-map request-matcher="ant">
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/login/**" filters="samlEntryPoint"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/logout/**" filters="samlLogoutFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/metadata/**" filters="metadataDisplayFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSO/**" filters="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SSOHoK/**" filters="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/SingleLogout/**" filters="samlLogoutProcessingFilter"/>
        <security:filter-chain pattern="/saml/discovery/**" filters="samlIDPDiscovery"/>
    </security:filter-chain-map>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after successful login -->
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/"/>
    </bean>
    <!--
    Use the following for interpreting RelayState coming from unsolicited response as redirect URL:
    <bean id="successRedirectHandler" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLRelayStateSuccessHandler">
       <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
    </bean>
    -->

    <!-- Handler deciding where to redirect user after failed login -->
    <bean id="failureRedirectHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <property name="useForward" value="true"/>
    <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/error.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Handler for successful logout -->
    <bean id="successLogoutHandler" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/logout.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <!-- Register authentication manager for SAML provider -->
    <security:authentication-provider ref="samlAuthenticationProvider"/>     
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <!-- Logger for SAML messages and events -->
    <bean id="samlLogger" class="org.springframework.security.saml.log.SAMLDefaultLogger"/>

    <!-- Central storage of cryptographic keys -->
    <bean id="keyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
    <constructor-arg value="classpath:security/samlKeystore.jks"/>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="nalle123"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
        <entry key="apollo" value="nalle123"/>
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="apollo"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Entry point to initialize authentication, default values taken from properties file -->
    <bean id="samlEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLEntryPoint">
    <property name="defaultProfileOptions">
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileOptions">
        <property name="includeScoping" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- IDP Discovery Service -->
    <bean id="samlIDPDiscovery" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLDiscovery">
    <property name="idpSelectionPath" value="/WEB-INF/security/idpSelection.jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter automatically generates default SP metadata -->
    <!-- Added by Deepak -->    
    <bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
                <property name="entityId" value="urn:test:deepak:atlanta"/>
                <property name="requestSigned" value="false"/>
                <property name="wantAssertionSigned" value="false"/>                

            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>  

    <!-- The filter is waiting for connections on URL suffixed with filterSuffix and presents SP metadata there -->
    <bean id="metadataDisplayFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataDisplayFilter"/>

    <!-- SP & IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
    <bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.CachingMetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
        <!-- IDP Metadata configuration - paths to metadata of IDPs in circle of trust is here -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
            <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                    <constructor-arg value="/metadata/sso_circle_idp.xml"/>
                </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
            </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
            </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>

        <!-- SP (current application) IDP Metadata configuration -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="java.util.Timer"/>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <constructor-arg>
                        <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.ClasspathResource">
                            <constructor-arg value="/metadata/localhost_sp.xml"/>
                        </bean>
                    </constructor-arg>
                    <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                    <property name="local" value="true"/>
                    <property name="alias" value="urn:test:deepak:atlanta"/>
                    <property name="securityProfile" value="metaiop"/>                  
                    <property name="sslHostnameVerification" value="allowAll"/>                 
                    <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>                   
                    <!--<property name="signingKey" value="apollo"/>
                    <property name="encryptionKey" value="apollo"/> -->
                    <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false"/>
                    <!--<property name="idpDiscoveryURL"
                        value="https://www.server.com:8080/context/saml/discovery"/>
                    <property name="idpDiscoveryResponseURL"
                        value="https://www.server.com:8080/context/saml/login?disco=true"/>-->
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>   

        </list>
    </constructor-arg>

    <!-- OPTIONAL used when one of the metadata files contains information about this service provider -->
    <property name="hostedSPName" value="urn:test:deepak:atlanta"/>
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can tell the system which IDP should be used for authenticating user by default. -->
    <!-- <property name="defaultIDP" value="http://localhost:8080/opensso"/> -->
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML Authentication Provider responsible for validating of received SAML messages -->
    <!-- org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider -->

    <bean id="samlAuthenticationProvider" class="com.aci.uob.saml.ValidUOBUserAuthProvider">
    <!-- OPTIONAL property: can be used to store/load user data after login -->

    <property name="userDetails" ref="uobUserLocatorService" />

    </bean>

    <bean id="uobUserLocatorService" class="com.aci.uob.saml.ValidUOBUserSAMLUserDetailsService"/>


    <!-- Provider of default SAML Context -->
    <bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderImpl"/>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO profile messages -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Processing filter for WebSSO Holder-of-Key profile -->
    <bean id="samlWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLWebSSOHoKProcessingFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successRedirectHandler"/>
    <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureRedirectHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Logout handler terminating local session -->
    <bean id="logoutHandler"
      class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">
    <property name="invalidateHttpSession" value="false"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Override default logout processing filter with the one processing SAML messages -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="2" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Filter processing incoming logout messages -->
    <!-- First argument determines URL user will be redirected to after successful global logout -->
    <bean id="samlLogoutProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLLogoutProcessingFilter">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="successLogoutHandler"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref="logoutHandler"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Class loading incoming SAML messages from httpRequest stream -->
    <bean id="processor" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
        <ref bean="redirectBinding"/>
        <ref bean="postBinding"/>
        <ref bean="artifactBinding"/>
        <ref bean="soapBinding"/>
        <ref bean="paosBinding"/>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key WebSSO Assertion Consumer -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOprofileConsumer" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="webSSOprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Holder-of-Key Web SSO profile -->
    <bean id="hokWebSSOProfile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileConsumerHoKImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 ECP profile -->
    <bean id="ecpprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.WebSSOProfileECPImpl"/>

    <!-- SAML 2.0 Logout Profile -->
    <bean id="logoutprofile" class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.SingleLogoutProfileImpl"/>

    <!-- Bindings, encoders and decoders used for creating and parsing messages -->
    <bean id="postBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPostBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="redirectBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPRedirectDeflateBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="artifactBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPArtifactBinding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="velocityEngine"/>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.websso.ArtifactResolutionProfileImpl">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient">
            <constructor-arg>
                <bean class="org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager"/>
            </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </constructor-arg>
        <property name="processor">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.SAMLProcessorImpl">
            <constructor-arg ref="soapBinding"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="soapBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPSOAP11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="paosBinding" class="org.springframework.security.saml.processor.HTTPPAOS11Binding">
    <constructor-arg ref="parserPool"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library-->
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap"/>

    <!-- Initialization of the velocity engine -->
    <bean id="velocityEngine" class="org.springframework.security.saml.util.VelocityFactory" factory-method="getEngine"/>

    <!-- XML parser pool needed for OpenSAML parsing -->
    <bean id="parserPool" class="org.opensaml.xml.parse.StaticBasicParserPool" init-method="initialize">
    <property name="builderFeatures">
        <map>
        <entry key="http://apache.org/xml/features/dom/defer-node-expansion" value="false"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="parserPoolHolder" class="org.springframework.security.saml.parser.ParserPoolHolder"/>

</beans>
```

also what I import to IdP, is first dynamically generated via below url and then imported:
    https://HOST:PORT/{context}/saml/metadata
Here is the SP metadata file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><md:EntityDescriptor xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata" ID="urn_test_deepak_atlanta" entityID="urn:test:deepak:atlanta"><md:SPSSODescriptor AuthnRequestsSigned="false" WantAssertionsSigned="false" protocolSupportEnumeration="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><md:KeyDescriptor use="signing"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIDUjCCAjqgAwIBAgIEUOLIQTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJGSTEQMA4GA1UE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=</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor><md:KeyDescriptor use="encryption"><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIDUjCCAjqgAwIBAgIEUOLIQTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBrMQswCQYDVQQGEwJGSTEQMA4GA1UE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=</ds:X509Certificate>
</ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></md:KeyDescriptor><md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:8443/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SingleLogout"/>
<md:SingleLogoutService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect" Location="https://localhost:8443/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SingleLogout"/><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:unspecified</md:NameIDFormat><md:NameIDFormat>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:X509SubjectName</md:NameIDFormat>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="https://localhost:8443/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO" index="0" isDefault="true"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" Location="https://localhost:8443/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO" index="1"/>
</md:SPSSODescriptor></md:EntityDescriptor>
```

I am using the SSOcircle as IDP in this case.

when I ask tomcat to accept the http also and change the SP's end point url to http (and port 8080) instead of https (and port 8443) - SSO work very well.

IDP also only accepts the https protocal, which seems work well for it.

What could be the reason of this not working on SP side for https?

Comment: Please include your complete Spring Security configuration. Are you using automatic metadata generation? Have you tried setting the entityBaseURL, as is described in the manual?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, Here is what I was doing wrong:

In the local sp metadata file which I was loading into the spring, was having the http & 8080... so SP always knew of this URL (http and 8080) only, even though what I imported to IDP was having https & 8443.

AuthnRequest to the browser by SP contains the URL, which was having the wrong URL, so having the correct end points (https & 8443) in the local_sp.xml SOLVED the issue.

snippet of AuthnRequest sent via SP to the browser -->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2p:AuthnRequest xmlns:saml2p="urn:oas
is:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://localhost:84
43/spring-security-saml2-sample/saml/SSO" Destination="https://idp.ssocircle.com
:443/sso/SSORedirect/metaAlias/ssocircle" ForceAuthn="false" ID="a106cccba5j1eje
9231aj76843b0j53" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2015-02-06T20:50:27.215Z" Prot
ocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0">
   <saml2:Issuer xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:test:de
epak:atlanta</saml2:Issuer>
</saml2p:AuthnRequest>
```